# The arc-length is a differentiable function of $t$, and $\frac{ds}{dt}=\vert \alpha'(t)\vert$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, curves

I'm reviewing curves using the introductory chapters of a differential geometry book (Manfredo's book). He says something like the following:

The arc length of a regular parametrized curve $\alpha:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ from the point $t_0$ is defined to be
$$
s(t)=\int_{t_0}^t \vert \alpha'(u)\vert du
$$
with $\alpha'(t)=\sqrt{(x'(t))^2+(y'(t))^2+(z'(t))^2}$.
Since $\alpha'(t) \ne 0$ for all $t$,the arc-length is a differentiable function of $t$, and $\frac{ds}{dt}=\vert \alpha'(t)\vert$.

**My problem:**
Why does it follow from $\alpha'(t) \ne 0$ that $s$ is differentiable?

**My attempt:**
The (second) fundamental theorem of calculus states that

> Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and $f=g'$, then 
>   $$
> \int_a^b f(x)dx=g(b)-g(a)
> $$

In our case, the function $\alpha'$ is continuous, and hence integrable. But, in order to apply the f.t.c, we need to see that *its modulus* $f=\vert \alpha' \vert$ is integrable, and also that $\vert \alpha' \vert = g'$ for some function $g$. Since $\alpha'$ is continuous and the modulus function is also continuous, $\vert \alpha'\vert$, being the composition of those, is continuous, and thus integrable. Also, $\vert \alpha'\vert=\frac{d}{dt} \vert \alpha\vert$ (*Question 1: is this true? Why? Is this where I use that $\alpha \ne 0$?*) So, using the f.t.c, we get 
$$
s(t)=\vert \alpha(t)\vert - \vert \alpha(t_0)\vert
$$
so
$$
\frac{ds}{dt}(t)=\vert \alpha'(t)\vert - \frac{d}{dt}\vert \alpha(t_0)\vert=\vert \alpha'(t)\vert
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you note, we'll be in good shape if we can conclude that the assignment $t\mapsto|\alpha'(t)|$ is continuous, because then the (first) fundamental theorem of calculus will allow us to conclude that
\begin{equation}
s(t):=\int_{t_0}^t |\alpha'(u)|du
\end{equation}
is differentiable, and that $s'(t)=|\alpha'(t)|$.  Since both $\alpha\colon I\to\mathbb{R}^3$ and the modulus map $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ are continuous, so is their composition, so $s(t)$ is differentiable.

So the condition that $\alpha'(t)$ should never vanish isn't necessary for the arc length to be differentiable.  Bill Cook points out in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/923739/) that we include this condition because it guarantees that we always have $s'(t)>0$.  This means that $s(t)$ is strictly increasing, and can thus be inverted.  So requiring that $\alpha'(t)\neq 0$ allows us to obtain an arclength parametrization of our curve.

---

**Edit:** We should also point out that $\frac{d}{dt}|\alpha(t)|\neq|\alpha'(t)|$.  You can work this out by unwinding what the two sides are in the components of $\alpha(t)$, but it might be more enlightening to think geometrically.  If $\alpha(t)$ takes all of its values in the unit sphere, then $|\alpha(t)|=1$, so $\frac{d}{dt}|\alpha(t)|=0$.  But certainly there are curves in the sphere with nonzero tangent vector, so our equality can't be true.

Comment: I was about to answer. It's important to emphasize that it's the *first* Fundamental Theorem of Calculus that's relevant here, not the second. :)

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out!